# How to run a Docker image that uses OpenCV GUI inside a Google Cloud Run container

Tags: docker, opencv, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, google-cloud-run

As part of a webapp, I developed a FastAPI backend that makes heavy use of OpenCV's GUI (namely: cv2.selectROI). Everything works perfectly when I run it locally. However, when deployed with its frontend (ReactJS) on Google Cloud Run or when I try to run the Docker image through the terminal I run into the following error:

```
bbox_in = cv2.selectROI("Select bounding box for inner circle tracking...", frame, True, False)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

I assume the issue must stem from the fact that OpenCV needs to have access to the user's display in order to open its GUI windows, however I did try to run the docker image with this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti --net=host --ipc=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix dockerusername/project_name
```

and I had no luck there either.

My question is the following: is there any way to make the code work as is on cloud run (by modifying the Dockerfile for example)? If so, any help is welcomed.

I was also thinking that I could integrate the GUI windows within the website instead of having them open like pop-ups (if that makes sense) but I'm not sure how to go about it either.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), paste the error as text instead.

Comment: @M.O. Hi, sorry. I've replaced the image with text.

Comment: With that said, the window that `cv2.selectROI` opens is a OS window on the computer running the API, meaning it's trying to open a window inside cloud run, which doesn't work, since those don't have screens. So if you want to run the API anywhere except for your own computer, using `selectROI` (or any of the high level functions that open GUI windows) will not work.

Comment: Adding onto what @M.O. said, you'll need to modify it in some way so that the frontend opens the image, not the backend. You'll need to send the image to the ReactJS frontend so that it can display the image.

Comment: @ShackUnderflow Thank you for your answer. Any idea on how I could integrate the GUI windows to the frontend? Is there any JS library I could use or anything similar? I'm not really sure where to start..

Comment: @Inès Sorry, I have no idea. I don't do JS at all. It might be better to create a new post asking how to display an image sent from a server in ReactJS.

Comment: As far as I understand you GUI is not only browser-based and it runs some native system UI. That's not compliant  with Cloud Run scope nor with a React app.